# Populating fields with data from database Joomla article/module position?

Tags: database, joomla, field

I was wondering if any of you have experience with placing fields within a Joomla page.
I have a client who want's to create an employee portal.
The clients log in with their number, name and password and after that get directed to a page.
They can view their records. All if this is already placed in the database of Joomla.

Here is an example mockup:
[image: example of page with fields]

I haven't got a clue where to start.
Maybe one of you have some experience.

Cheers and thanks in advance.

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Right, something to get you started off. You will need to firstly get the data from the database like so:

```
//database connection
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

//get the user object
$user = JFactory::getUser();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select('*');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__table_name'));
// where the username in the database table matches the username of the client logged in
$query->where($db->quoteName('username')." = ".$db->quote($user->username)); 
$query->order('ordering ASC');

$db->setQuery($query);

$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
   echo "<p>" . $row->nummer . "</p>";
   echo "<p>" . $row->functie . "</p>";
   //and so on
}
```

Don't forget to change the `table_name` to whatever suits your needs. If it's a Joomla database table that contains the prefix at the beginning like all the others, then keep the `#__` at the beginning on the name in the query above.

As commented in the query, in the `where` statement, the username in the database needs to match the username of the client currently logged in. You can of course change this to something like `id` or whatever you wish.

**Update:**

*Where do I place this code?*

Well it depends. If you want to use it to simply display the data without the possibility of the user updating it, the you could always download [Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051) which will allow you to use PHP within an article. This would be the "quick method".

If you want the user to be able to update the information or simply would rather compile everything useing better methods/practices, then I would recommend developing a small component. Doing this would be more flexible should you ever want to update anything, add new features etc etc. For a guide on how to develop a component, have a read of this:

http://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Component_Development

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Lodder,

Thanks for the feedback. Is this code placed directly into the page?

The data is stored in the Joomla database as tfv_employee. Here we have all the fields (see the example image) which come straight out of the database.

Cheers,

Steve

Cheers, 

Steve

Comment: Hi Steve, I've updated my answer with a little more information and additional resources

Comment: Hi Lodder,
Thanks again. I'll give it a try and let you know.
In this case the user can't make changes, so Sourcerer it is ;-)

Comment: Hi all, Thanks to lodder I got this working.

I used Flexi custom code extension for adding code to the site.

// where the username in the database table matches the username of the client logged in
$query->where($db->quoteName('nummer')." = ".$db->quote($user->pin));

Cheers Steve

Comment: I do have one question.

We're using LDAP for the login. This is working now.
Each user is part of a group and has his or her own path.

How can I let people **download** pdf files coming from this path?

If you see ID Bestand, id_datum_kopie you'll also notice a download button. 

How does this work?

Cheers,

Steve

Comment: @Steve - I know this was some time ago but it looks like you didn't accept Lodder's answer.  Did his answer resolved your query?